# Issue marshalling XML tags with IDRef when using MOXy

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, weblogic, moxy

I had a question regarding MOXy:

Assume that a web service has the following request XML -

```
<A>
    <B ref="123" />
</A>
<C id="123">
    ...
</C>
```

When the web service was called on WebLogic 10.3.4, the following java code was working:

```
a.getB().getRef(); //Returns C
```

However, when we deployed the code onto our integration servers (using weblogic 12C, which uses MOXy), the getRef() would always return null. I've been going crazy trying to figure out what the issue could be - Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I have already seen some of Blaise Doughan's posts, but unfortunately, as the marshalling is happening at the server level (ie. not in code), there isn't much I can do to customize what's happening.

Also, we don't get this issue when we use the following jar: org.eclipse.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-3.jar. However, when we upgraded this to org.eclipse.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-5.jar (because of a bug fix required for another service), the references do not get resolved. We have tried all the versions in the middle of these 2 as well, but the version above is the only one where our other issue was fixed, so that doesn't really help us too much. If anyone has any idea about how we can solve this, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I have not been able to reproduce the issue you are seeing.  Below is what I have tried based on this question and some additional information you have sent me by email.  Could you send me a standalone test case similar to the one below that demonstrates the issue.  You can download EclipseLink from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

### Java Model

**Root**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="ROOT")
public class Root {

    A a;
    C c;

    @XmlElement(name="A")
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="C")    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

**A**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class A {

    B b;

    @XmlElement(name="B")
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

**B**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class B {

    Object ref;

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    public Object getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(Object ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

}
```

**C**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;

public class C {

    String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class) 
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <A>
        <B ref="123" />
    </A>
    <C id="123">
        ...
    </C>
</ROOT>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.Version;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, C.class);
        System.out.println(jc.getClass());
        System.out.println(Version.getVersion());

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18661636/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
2.5.0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
   <A>
      <B ref="123"/>
   </A>
   <C id="123"/>
</ROOT>
```